# Merging rows in dynamically binded apex:pageblockTable in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I am new to Salesforce VF pages. I have a dynamically binded pageBlockTable in my Visualforce page. I wanted to merge certain dynamic rows based on a condition. Could someone please suggest, if there is any possible way to merge rows(or subrows) in apex:pageblocktable based on some conditions?

I have tried googling this, but could find no clues. 
Any help is really appreciated.

Visualforce page code:

```
<apex:pageblock id="listBlock">
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!lstcomp}" var="oComp"   styleclass="table table-striped table-hover" id="sysTable" rowClasses="even,odd">

<apex:column headerClass="TableTitle" style="width: 20%;height:4%"  ><apex:facet name="header"><font class="headerfontstyle" >Name</font></apex:facet> 
<font class="rowdatastyle"> {!oComp.Name} </font>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerClass="TableTitle" style="width: 10%;height:4%"  ><apex:facet name="header"><font class="headerfontstyle" >Mfg</font></apex:facet> 
<font class="rowdatastyle" >  {!oComp.Manufacturer}</font>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerClass="TableTitle" style="width: 6%;height:4%"><apex:facet name="header"><font class="headerfontstyle" >Type</font></apex:facet> 
<font class="rowdatastyle" > {!oComp.ComponentType} </font>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerClass="TableTitle" style="width: 12%;height:4%"><apex:facet name="header"><font class="headerfontstyle" >Allocated</font></apex:facet>  
<font class="rowdatastyle"> {!oComp.Allocated} </font>
</apex:column>                                                        
<apex:column headerClass="TableTitle" style="width: 10%;height:4%"><apex:facet name="header"><font class="headerfontstyle" >Used</font></apex:facet>  
<font class="rowdatastyle"> {!oComp.Used} </font>
</apex:column>                                                        
<apex:column headerClass="TableTitle" style="width: 30%;height:4%"><apex:facet name="header"><font class="headerfontstyle" >Version</font></apex:facet>  
<font class="rowdatastyle">{!oComp.OS} </font>
</apex:column>         
</apex:pageblockTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group your records base on certain conditions and show the rest of fields as from child records.

```
<apex:pageblockTable>
    <apex:column value="{!acc.name}">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header"> Team Members </apex:facet>
        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!acc.AccountTeamMembers}" var="tm">
            <apex:column headerValue="Team Member">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!tm.User.Name}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Role">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!tm.TeamMemberRole}"/>
            </apex:column>                          
        </apex:pageblocktable>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageblockTable>
```